# Trying to use '\' with 'os.startfile' in python, when taking variables from excel using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I am having issues trying to open jpg files with python, when I'm taking there names from excel.

Here's what I have so far in code:

```
print(worksheet.cell(rowidx,2))
image = worksheet.cell(rowidx,11)
print(image)
image_name = str(image).replace("'","")
print(image_name)
image_name2 = image_name.replace("text:","")
print(image_name2)
os.startfile(image_name2)
```

I used the `print` function to help me debug.

Whenever an input goes in, for this example let's say `"d:\cow.jpg"`, the following output is displayed:

```
text:'d:\\cow.jpg'
text:d:\\cow.jpg
d:\\cow.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    generate(1, all, all, all, all, 1, 1, "Murloc")
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Dropbox\Documents\Python\Random Hearthstone Card
Gen\Random Hearthstone Card Generator.py", line 38, in generate
    os.startfile(image_name2)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 15] The system cannot find the drive specified:
'd:\\\\cow.jpg'
```

Comment: From the output it looks like the cell actually contains a path with double underscores in it, which is wrong. It should just have, literally, `text:'d:\cow.jpg'`. How did the contents in the cell get there (i.e. what created it)?

Comment: I created the contents in the cell, simply typing them in it. Do I need to change the cell type or anything? (I'm storing  it in a general cell now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!
I just changed the cell type from general to text, and replaced the \ with a \\.